# md-checkbox does not work with ng-click

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I want to save position each time when I change checkbox:

```
<h1 class="md-display-2">Simple TODO ng app</h1>

<h2 class="md-display-3"></h2>

<div ng-include src="'todo/add.html'"></div>

<div>
    <div layout="row">
        <div flex class="md-title">Scope</div>
        <div flex="10" class="md-title">Till date</div>
        <div flex="10" class="md-title">Is reached?</div>
        <div flex="10" class="md-title">
            <span ng-click="todoctrl.show_add()" class="material-icons controls">add</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div layout="row" ng-repeat="todo in todoctrl.todos track by $index">
        <div flex ng-class="{true:'striked', false:'simple'}[todo.reached]">{{todo.name}}</div>
        <div flex="10">
            {{todo.tillDate | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}} 
        </div>
        <div flex="10">
            <md-checkbox ng-model="todo.reached" aria-label="Is reached" ng-click="todoctrl.changeState(todo.name)"></md-checkbox>
        </div>
        <div flex="10">
            <span ng-click="todoctrl.deleteScope(todo.name)"
                class="material-icons controls">clear</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this case controller is touched (I tried with to debug with console log), but the checkbox value is not changed before page reload. After reload the value is checkbox is presented as expected.
If I remove `ng-click="todoctrl.changeState(todo.name)"` then checkbox is working good, but no info is sent to controller.

This is my service:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('app').service('ToDoService', ToDoService);
    ToDoService.$inject = ['JsonService'];

    function ToDoService(JsonService) {

        return {
            deleteScope : deleteScope,
            submitScope : submitScope,
            changeState : changeState,
            getData : getData
        }

        function getData() {
            var todos = JsonService.getData();
            return todos;
        }

        function deleteScope(arr, scope) {
            arr.splice(findElementByScope(arr, scope), 1);
            JsonService.setData(arr);
        }

        function submitScope(arr, scope, tillDate) {
            var newTodo = {};
            newTodo.name = scope;
            newTodo.reached = false;
            newTodo.tillDate = tillDate;
            arr.push(newTodo);
            JsonService.setData(arr);
        }

        function changeState(arr, scope) {
            console.log("Service change state for scope: " + scope);
            var todo = {};
            var index = findElementByScope(arr, scope);
            todo = arr[index];
            todo.reached = !todo.reached;
            JsonService.setData(arr);
        }

        function findElementByScope(arr, scope) {
            for (var i = arr.length; i--;) {
                if (arr[i].name == scope) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }
    }
})();
```

And this is the Controller:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app').controller('ToDoController', ToDoController);

    function ToDoController(ToDoService) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.show_form = false;
        vm.todos = ToDoService.getData();
        vm.scope = '';

        vm.show_add = show_add;
        vm.submitScope = submitScope;
        vm.deleteScope = deleteScope;
        vm.changeState = changeState;

        function show_add() {
            console.log("Controller show add");
            vm.show_form = true;
        }

        function submitScope() {
            ToDoService.submitScope(vm.todos, vm.scope, vm.tillDate);
            vm.show_form = false;
            vm.scope = '';
        }

        function deleteScope(scope) {
            ToDoService.deleteScope(vm.todos, scope);
        }

        function changeState(scope) {
            ToDoService.changeState(vm.todos, scope);
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: use ng-change instead of ng-click

Comment: I tried ng-change, in this case no info is sent also the value of checkbox is not changed.

Comment: ng-change="todoctrl.changeState(todo.name, todo.reached)" pass like this

Comment: Yeah! It works now! But why??? P.S. Can you provide your comment as answer for this question?

Comment: Yess I came across this issue too. Really awful.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use `ng-change` instead of `ng-click`

```
<md-checkbox ng-model="todo.reached" aria-label="Is reached" ng-change="todoctrl.changeState(todo.name, todo.reached)"></md-checkbox>
```

`ng-change` trigger after value change in model

Comment: Thank you. But why ng-model does not trigger the model? With simple Input type checkbox it worked.

Comment: @Filosssof ng-click trigger before value change

Comment: No, you did not understand me, I ask why I need send todo.reached in ng-change? I have a model binded to this checkbox and when ng-changed is fired the model should be changed, and from service I have to operate with changed model.